# Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : longitude > 360 with calculating distance

Tags: r, distance

Im trying to calculate the nearest distance to a point. Therefore I create two df's

Create list 1

```
long <- c(52.070498, 52.370216, 52.632381, 53.201233, 51.813298, 51.92442, 52.266075, 53.219383, 52.960561, 52.367027, 51.571915, 52.516775, 51.441642, 52.221537, 52.090737, 51.985103, 51.560596)
lat <- c(4.3007, 4.895168,4.753375, 5.799913, 4.690093, 4.477733, 6.155217, 6.566502, 5.920522, 6.668492, 4.768323, 6.083022, 5.469722, 6.893662, 5.12142, 5.89873, 5.091914)

stad <- c("Den Haag", "Amsterdam", "Alkmaar", "Leeuwarden", "Dordrecht", "Rotterdam", "Deventer", "Groningen", "Heerenveen", "Almelo", "Breda", "Zwolle", "Eindhoven", "Enschede", "Utrecht", "Arnhem", "Tilburg")
list1 <- data.frame(longitude=long, latitude=lat, stad)
```

Create list 2

```
long <- c("51.476364", "52.12379", "52.456954", "51.543197", "52.307687", "53.250184", "52.640436", "53.397875", "52.491691", "52.109272", "52.121092", "52.882946", "52.518537", "53.201233", "52.711559", "52.066719", "53.405366", "52.433881", "53.128855", "51.641078", "53.189226", "52.716927", "51.453667", "51.233528", "51.529207", "51.980632", "51.429248", "51.92442", "51.441642", "50.851368")
lat <- c("6.180948", "4.438598", "4.606014", "6.087664", "4.767424", "4.951427", "4.998517", "5.346679", "4.593325", "5.180968", "5.285347", "5.360707", "5.471422", "5.799913", "5.864559", "5.894033", "6.212048", "6.232888", "6.587567", "5.619458", "7.162511", "5.737644", "3.570912", "3.830322", "3.89688", "4.134185", "4.304708", "4.477733", "5.469722", "5.690973")
stad <- c("Valkenburg", "Voorschoten", "Ijmuiden", "De kooy", "Schiphol", "Vlieland", "Berkhout", "Hoorn (terschelling)", "Wijk aan zee", "De Bilt", "Soesterberg", "Stavoren", "Lelystad", "Leeuwarden", "Marknesse", "Deelen", "Lauwersoog", "Heino", "Eelde", "Hupsel", "Nieuwe beerta", "Twente", "Vlissingen", "Westdorpe", "Wilhelminadorp", "Hoek van Holland", "Woensdrecht", "Rotterdam", "Eindhoven", "Maastricht")
list2 <- data.frame(longitude=long, latitude=lat , stad)
```

But then when I do:

```
 library(geosphere)
 mat <- distm(list1[,c('longitude','latitude')], list2[,c('longitude','latitude')], fun=distVincentyEllipsoid)
```

I get:

```
Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : longitude > 360
list1$locality <- list2$stad[apply(mat, 1, which.min)]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Where is `df_steden` ? `df_weerstations` ? why `list1` and `list2` are not used in the code ?

Comment: @dickoa Im sorry, ive create a better, reproducable example. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is that `list2` contains factors instead of floats in `longitude` and `latitude` columns.

It seems to work once you convert factor values to numerical values specified by labels:

```
list2$longitude.fix <- as.numeric(levels(list2$longitude))[list2$longitude]
list2$latitude.fix <- as.numeric(levels(list2$latitude))[list2$latitude]
```

```
distm(list1[,c('longitude','latitude')], list2[,c('longitude.fix','latitude.fix')], fun=distVincentyEllipsoid)
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      …
 [1,] 218106.26  16356.00  54584.86 206073.80  57935.42 149371.56  99767.31 187239.60      …
 [2,] 173280.56  57416.26  33391.75 160587.51  15737.20  97796.65  32074.61 124403.87      …
 [3,] 203303.45  66306.56  25384.63 190634.04  36054.40  71943.23  27123.09 107285.19      …
 [4,] 195563.08 192179.83 155688.71 186323.20 151151.41  93985.73 108243.57  54651.40      …
 [5,] 169040.53  44278.35  72020.04 157421.51  55511.66 161989.79  97883.85 190131.21      …
 …
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second list you have Strings.

```
long <- as.numeric(c("51.476364", "52.12379", "52.456954", "51.543197", "52.307687", "53.250184", "52.640436", "53.397875", "52.491691", "52.109272", "52.121092", "52.882946", "52.518537", "53.201233", "52.711559", "52.066719", "53.405366", "52.433881", "53.128855", "51.641078", "53.189226", "52.716927", "51.453667", "51.233528", "51.529207", "51.980632", "51.429248", "51.92442", "51.441642", "50.851368"))
lat <- as.numeric(c("6.180948", "4.438598", "4.606014", "6.087664", "4.767424", "4.951427", "4.998517", "5.346679", "4.593325", "5.180968", "5.285347", "5.360707", "5.471422", "5.799913", "5.864559", "5.894033", "6.212048", "6.232888", "6.587567", "5.619458", "7.162511", "5.737644", "3.570912", "3.830322", "3.89688", "4.134185", "4.304708", "4.477733", "5.469722", "5.690973"))
stad <- c("Valkenburg", "Voorschoten", "Ijmuiden", "De kooy", "Schiphol", "Vlieland", "Berkhout", "Hoorn (terschelling)", "Wijk aan zee", "De Bilt", "Soesterberg", "Stavoren", "Lelystad", "Leeuwarden", "Marknesse", "Deelen", "Lauwersoog", "Heino", "Eelde", "Hupsel", "Nieuwe beerta", "Twente", "Vlissingen", "Westdorpe", "Wilhelminadorp", "Hoek van Holland", "Woensdrecht", "Rotterdam", "Eindhoven", "Maastricht")
list2 <- data.frame(longitude=long, latitude=lat , star)
```

or you just remove the quotes