# Conditional updating coordinate column in dataframe

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial

I am attempting to populate two newly empty columns in a data frame with data from other columns in the same data frame in different ways depending on if they are populated.

I am trying to populate the values of HIGH_PRCN_LAT and HIGH_PRCN_LON (previously called F_Lat and F_Lon) which represent the final latitudes and londitudes for those rows this will be based off the values of the other columns in the table.

Case 1: Lat/Lon2 are populated (like in IDs 1 & 2), using the great
   circle algorithm a midpoint between them should be calculated and
   then placed into F_Lat & F_Lon.

Case 2: Lat/Lon2 are empty, then the values of Lat/Lon1 should be put
   into F_Lat and F_Lon (like with IDs 3 & 4).

My code is as follows but doesn't work (see previous versions, removed in an edit).

The preperatory code I am using is as follows:

```r
incidents <- structure(list(id = 1:9, StartDate = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("02/02/2000 00:34", "02/09/2000 22:13", 
"20/01/2000 14:11"), class = "factor"), EndDate = structure(1:9, .Label = c("02/04/2006 20:46", 
"02/04/2006 22:38", "02/04/2006 23:21", "02/04/2006 23:59", "03/04/2006 20:12", 
"03/04/2006 23:56", "04/04/2006 00:31", "07/04/2006 06:19", "07/04/2006 07:45"
), class = "factor"), Yr.Period = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2000 / 1", "2000 / 2", "2000 /3"
), class = "factor"), Description = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ENGLISH TEXT", class = "factor"), 
    Location = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Location 1", "Location 1 : Location 2"), class = "factor"), 
    Location.1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "Location 1", class = "factor"), Postcode.1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Postcode 1", class = "factor"), 
    Location.2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "Location 2"), class = "factor"), Postcode.2 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Postcode 2"
    ), class = "factor"), Section = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("East", "North", "South", 
    "West"), class = "factor"), Weather.Category = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Animals", "Food", 
    "Humans", "Weather"), class = "factor"), Minutes = c(13L, 
    55L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 522L, 1L, 11L, 22L), Cost = c(150L, 150L, 
    150L, 20L, 23L, 32L, 21L, 11L, 23L), Location.1.Lat = c(53.0506727, 
    53.8721035, 51.0233529, 53.8721035, 53.6988355, 53.4768766, 
    52.6874562, 51.6638245, 51.4301359), Location.1.Lon = c(-2.9991256, 
    -2.4004125, -3.0988341, -2.4004125, -1.3031529, -2.2298073, 
    -1.8023421, -0.3964916, 0.0213837), Location.2.Lat = c(52.7116187, 
    53.746791, NA, 53.746791, 53.6787167, 53.4527824, 52.5264907, 
    NA, NA), Location.2.Lon = c(-2.7493169, -2.4777984, NA, -2.4777984, 
    -1.489026, -2.1247029, -1.4645023, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

#gpsColumns is used as the following line of code is used for several data frames.
gpsColumns <- c("HIGH_PRCN_LAT", "HIGH_PRCN_LON")
incidents [ , gpsColumns] <- NA

#create separate variable(?) containing a list of which rows are complete
ind <- complete.cases(incidents [,17])

#populate rows with a two Lat/Lons with great circle middle of both values
incidents [ind, c("HIGH_PRCN_LON_2","HIGH_PRCN_LAT_2")] <- 
  with(incidents [ind,,drop=FALSE],
       do.call(rbind, geosphere::midPoint(cbind.data.frame(Location.1.Lon, Location.1.Lat), cbind.data.frame(Location.2.Lon, Location.2.Lat))))

#populate rows with one Lat/Lon with those values
incidents[!ind, c("HIGH_PRCN_LAT","HIGH_PRCN_LON")] <- incidents[!ind, c("Location.1.Lat","Location.1.Lon")]
```

I will use the geosphere::midPoint function based off a recommendation here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Midpoint-between-coordinates-td2299999.html.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that this way of populating the column will work when there are several cases.

The current error that is thrown is:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, F_Lat, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 178012
```

Edit: also posted to reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Rlanguage/comments/bdvavx/conditional_updating_column_in_dataframe/

Edit: Added clarity on the parts of the code I do not understand.

```r
#replaces the F_Lat2/F_Lon2 columns in rows with a both sets of input coordinates 
dataframe[ind, c("F_Lat2","F_Lon2")] <-
#I am unclear on what this means, specifically what the "with" function does and what "drop=FALSE" does and also why they were used in this case.
  with(dataframe[ind,,drop=FALSE],
#I am unclear on what do.call and rbind are doing here, but the second half (geosphere onwards) is binding the Lats and Lons to make coordinates as inputs for the gcIntermediate function.
       do.call(rbind, geosphere::gcIntermediate(cbind.data.frame(Lat1, Lon1),
                                                cbind.data.frame(Lat2, Lon2), n = 1)))
```

Comment: (1) I reformatted the question slightly so that it's easier to copy the frame into a local R session. (2) I'm not familiar with your notation of `gcIntermediate([dataframe$Lat1,dataframe$Lon1],...)`. Specifically, the bracket by itself. Am I missing something? I don't think that code should work. (I get an error: `unexpected '['`.)

Comment: I suggest you copy/paste your sample data and code from this question into a fresh (clean!) R session to see what is missing/wrong from your code here.

Comment: Thank you for making the change to improve the formating of the data. 
As for the second question I was aiming to use columns in the data frame as input for the gcIntermediate function to avoid making a new dataframe or columns. I thought that gcIntermediate took an input of two groups of coordinates, so I was attempting to format the existing data to work with those inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your code doesn't work as-written for me, and I cannot calculate the same precise values your expect, I suspect the error your seeing can be fixed with these steps. (Data is down at the bottom here.)

1. Pre-populate the empty columns.
2. Pre-calculate the `complete.cases` step, it'll save time.
3. Use `cbind.data.frame` for inside `gcIntermediate`.

I'm inferring from

```
gcIntermediate([dataframe...
               ^
               this is an error in R
```

that you are binding those columns together, so I'll use `cbind.data.frame`. (Using `cbind` itself produced some ignorable warnings from `geosphere`, so you can use it instead and perhaps `suppressWarnings`, but that function is a little strong in that it'll mask other warnings as well.)

Also, since it appears you want *one* intermediate value for each pair of coordinates, I added the `gcIntermediate(..., n=1)` argument.

The use of `do.call(rbind, ...)` is because `gcIntermediate` returns a `list`, so we need to bring them together.

```r
dataframe$F_Lon2 <- dataframe$F_Lat2 <- NA_real_
ind <- complete.cases(dataframe[,4])

dataframe[ind, c("F_Lat2","F_Lon2")] <- 
  with(dataframe[ind,,drop=FALSE],
       do.call(rbind, geosphere::gcIntermediate(cbind.data.frame(Lat1, Lon1),
                                                cbind.data.frame(Lat2, Lon2), n = 1)))
dataframe[!ind, c("F_Lat2","F_Lon2")] <- dataframe[!ind, c("Lat1","Lon1")]
dataframe
#   ID     Lat1      Lon1     Lat2      Lon2    F_Lat     F_Lon   F_Lat2    F_Lon2
# 1  1 19.05067 -3.999126 92.71332 -6.759169 55.88200 -5.379147 55.78466 -6.709509
# 2  2 58.87210 -1.400413 54.74679 -4.479840 56.80945 -2.940126 56.81230 -2.942029
# 3  3 33.02335 -5.098834       NA        NA 33.02335 -5.098834 33.02335 -5.098834
# 4  4 54.87210 -4.400412       NA        NA 54.87210 -4.400412 54.87210 -4.400412
```

**Update**, using your new `incidents` data and switching to `geosphere::midPoint`.

Try this:

```r
incidents$F_Lon2 <- incidents$F_Lat2 <- NA_real_
ind <- complete.cases(incidents[,4])

incidents[ind, c("F_Lat2","F_Lon2")] <- 
  with(incidents[ind,,drop=FALSE],
       geosphere::midPoint(cbind.data.frame(Location.1.Lat,Location.1.Lon),
                           cbind.data.frame(Location.2.Lat,Location.2.Lon)))
incidents[!ind, c("F_Lat2","F_Lon2")] <- dataframe[!ind, c("Lat1","Lon1")]
```

One (big) difference is that `geosphere::gcIntermediate(..., n=1)` returns a list of results, whereas `geosphere::midPoint(...)` (no `n=`) returns just a matrix, so no `rbind`ing required.

---

Data:

```r
dataframe <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, text="
ID Lat1       Lon1       Lat2      Lon2      F_Lat       F_Lon
1  19.0506727 -3.9991256 92.713318 -6.759169 55.88199535 -5.3791473
2  58.8721035 -1.4004125 54.746791 -4.47984  56.80944725 -2.94012625
3  33.0233529 -5.0988341 NA        NA        33.0233529  -5.0988341
4  54.8721035 -4.4004125 NA        NA        54.8721035  -4.4004125")
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. There are a few thing that I'd like to clarify because my knowledge of r is currently quite limited.
1) My expected values were not calculated using the gcIntermediate function because I was unable to get it to work so I used a different method that produced similar but not identical values. I will update the original post with the correct expected values.

Comment: 2) I am confused as to why F_Lat2 & F_Lon2 were created (their role) and how their values are generated as compared to F_Lat & F_Lon. 3) I am confused by what most of the code/functions on your 3rd and 4th lines of data are doing, it would be useful if you could explain this please? 4) I have checked the documentation for gcIntermediate and am not able to find an explanation of what an intermediate value is? In my experimentaion it looks to generate more values (and automatically populate the F_Lat2 & F_Lon2 but I'm not certain)

Comment: Another item I have noticed is that gcIntemediate takes LON, LAT as input, which goes against the normal standard but means that the data is being input in the opposite order in your example.

Comment: I have adapted your code to the dataset I am using (changing column & data frame names) alongside switching Lat/Lon columns in the gcIntermediate input but have now encountered an error (wasn't sure if I should make a new post, update this or comment, let me know if there is a more appropriate way). "Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : longitude > 360" there are several SO threads about this error (1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576333/error-in-pointstomatrixx-longitude-360-with-calculating-distance, 2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496587/error-in-pointstomatrixp1-latitude-90).

Comment: However when I run the as.numeric on my longditude columns, the data is replaced with whole numbers with more than 50% of them being larger than 360, and I am having a hard time understanding what formula is used to calcuate these numbers. I have also changed the format of these columns to numbers in the CSV file that contains the data in the hopes that they would be imported as numerical values in the first place but that hasn't solved it. Apologies for the wall of text and thank you for your help so far, any further help is also highly appreciated.

Comment: (1) Got it, your numbers are estimates? It might be nice to say that in future questions so that people don't try to match your numbers. (2) `F_Lat2` was purely for *your benefit* to show my numbers and your numbers side-by-side. (3) Please be specific about functions you don't understand. (4) If you don't understand what an intermediate value is, why are you using it? (5) Lon/Lat, Lat/Lon, preferences. (6) `longitude>360` means your data isn't what you say (or think) it is. (7) `as.numeric` on columns? Huh, I *really* don't know what you data is if this is a necessary step.

Comment: (1) Yes, my numbers were estimates and I now understand the value in being clear about that in the original post. (2) Thank you for clariying the role of F_Lat2/F_Lon2, that makes sense. (4) I am using the gcIntermediate as I believe that it will give me a more accurate midpoint between my two coordinates. I am not clear on how it could return several values however. (5) That function look to have had issues based on the order of Lat/Lon but I am not 100% sure [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496587/error-in-pointstomatrixp1-latitude-90/36139542#36139542).

Comment: (6) I've done more testing and you are correct about data not being as it seems. Although the input columns (Lat1/Lon1/Lat2/Lon2) list correct coordinates, once I run the line of your code starting `dataframe[!ind` they are transformed into whole numbers that are different from their original values. I have updated the original post with examples and will upload a csv file that can be used for testing. (7) I suspect that this step won't be needed once my data is corrected from the above problem.

Comment: (4) [`gcIntermediate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-5/topics/intermediate) provides *"intermediate points (way points) between the two locations with longitude/latitude coordinates. gcIntermediate is based on a spherical model of the earth"*. By default, it provides 50 intermediate points; I *assume* that `n=1` gives you the mid-way point, but I have not verified. (6) The links I suggested earlier strongly urge the use of `dput` for *unambiguous sample data*; links to data can and will go stale, rendering the question unreproducible. Please use `dput`.

Comment: (4) I have found a more relevant function, geosphere::midPoint() which will provide the sole midpoint and is much more relevant. It appears to take the coordinate inputs in the same fashion but does not require the `n=x` which is an improvement. (6) I have updated the post with the dput for the csv I linked. It doesn't appear that the coordinate columns are being considered as factors which was the problem I thought might be causing the odd translations.

Comment: Adding the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` parameter to the read CSV function looks to resolve the issue for the second case (no 2nd set of coordinates) but does not resolve the `Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : longitude < -360` for the first case (when there are two sets of coordinates).

Comment: I understand, unfortunately the sample you provided does not include any such errors. Perhaps if you look at `subset(incidents, !(-360 < Location.1.Lon & Location.1.Lon < 360) | !(-360 < Location.2.Lon & Location.2.Lon < 360))`, you'll see what problem rows you have in your data. (BTW: `geosphere::midPoint` looks like a much better choice. Nice.)

Comment: Thank you for the snipit to find out of range coordinates, the sample dataset doesn't return any results but when run against my main dataset it returns every single row. In rStudio's view tab the data looks the same though. Do you have any recommendations for determining the difference between them? Maybe my main dataset get imported in a wrong way so the numbers are formatted as strings or something do that effect.

Comment: _merged previous comments to save space_. 
I used `sapply(dataframe, class)` to find that my main dataset is storing my coordinates as character type and in the sample dataset they are stored as numeric type. Running as.numeric() on the main dataset's coordinates columns resolves this. midPoint accepts different inputs than gcIntermediate (which I have gotten to successfully run now) and I have not found a way to correctly format the coordinate inputs for the new function. Replacing `cbind.data.frame()` with `c()` which is recommended in the documentation doesn't work. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I can't really provide anything without seeing the errant data, sorry. If your data is reading `character` in those fields, I suggest you look at the read-in process to find out why `read.csv` really believes they should not be numbers; you might need to specify `na.strings=` to `read.csv` to force some *things* (e.g., `"N/A"`) to be interpreted as `NA`.

Comment: Your suggestion of adding `na.strings=` has resolved my issue with the coordinates columns not being the numeric type. Thank you once again. Regarding the error with the midPoint function, the code you kindly provided currently errors with the sample dataset, both of which are provided in the updated original post. It now throws the `Error in do.call(rbind, geosphere::midPoint(cbind.data.frame(Location.1.Lon,  : 
  second argument must be a list` error, which I am unclear on how to resolve.

Comment: Your edit has resolved the issue, I appreciate your patience given my limited knowledge of r and the help you have provided has been incredibly useful. By the way, should these comments be moved to the chat?

Comment: *This* comment I'm writing now has (finally?) triggered SO to suggest this should be moved to chat. It's not always necessary to move it to chat, especially since the issue is now resolved. (I prefer most content be available in comments anyway, as most people searching questions do not dive into the chat unless the comments after the "moved to chat" indicator suggest that the chat was influential. Even then, perhaps I'm the only one curious enough to read the chat, I don't know :-) (I do not believe we can manually move all of these to chat without moderator privileges.)